# Why if $p\not = q$ we have $L^p(R^n) \not \subseteq L^q(R^n)$?

Tags: lp-spaces

Why if $p\not = q$ we have $L^p(R^n) \not \subseteq L^q(R^n)$? This is a result present in my books, and I can't figure out really a nice proof about this.

An example say that the function $u(x) = (1+|x|)^{-n/p}$ is in all $L^q(R^n)$ with $q>p$ but not in  $L^p(R^n)$.

Another example say that the function $u(x) = 1_B|x|^{-n/p}$ is in all $L^q(R^n)$ ($B=B_1(0)$) with $q<p$ but not in  $L^p(R^n)$.

I can't figure out why those are verified. Also, $1_B$ is the ball $B=B_1(0)$? I've never used this notation on a function. Can someone explain me?

Comment: $1_B$ means equal to 1 on the ball and zero anywhere else.

Think of these functions as two different types.

The first type $u(x) = (1+|x|)^{-n/p}$ is kind of like the fact that $1/(1+x)$ integrates to infinity over an unbounded domain R+.

The second type $u(x) = 1_B |x|^{-n/p}$ is like how $1/x$ blows up at zero and is not integrable. 

The inclusions are different for the two types of blow up

Comment: Thanks. But why for the first case $q<p$ and for the second $q>p$? This is my great perplexity (my apology if this seems an incredibly trivial question)

Comment: It is because if you had say, $f(x) = 1/x^2$ around $0$, this blows up faster than $1/x$. So in general around the origin, higher powers means not in $L^p$.

At infinity (or on an unbounded positive domain), functions like $1/(1+x^2)$ do actually integrate, and higher powers than that will be in $L^1$, it is the lower powers that are not in $L^1$.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, for the second  case $f(x)=1/x$, beign slower than $f(x)=1/x^2$, its contained in the $L^2$ space. And for the first case, the  greater is the exponent the less it explode (due to the negative sign)..? For the equivalent, mean that $L^p$ not in itself (the last part of the two cases) it's because the blow up speed is the same? Or in this case am I missing something?

Comment: Let us talk of $L^1$. You can adjust the functions accordingly for $L^p$.

$f(x) = \mathbb{I}_B 1/x^{0.99999} \in L^1$


but $f(x) = \mathbb{I}_B 1/x \notin L^1$.

$f(x) = 1/(1+x^{1.00001}) \in L^1$


but $f(x) = 1/(1+x^1) \notin L^1$

Comment: Ok, thanks, it's more clear now. It's a way classify the different kind of divergent behavior of the functions according to the $L^p$ where you study it. Thank you George for the patience, probably I'll come up with more questions on the Lp spaces sub in the future. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1_B$ is the function defined by $1_B(x)=1$ if $x \in B$ and $0$ otherwise. To prove these facts you can use polar coordinates in $\mathbb R^{n}$. See Rudin's RCA for polar coordinates.

Comment: Thanks Kavi; can I have a link for Rudin's RCA? Also, in the $L_p$ spaces, the polar coordinates are always the right way to study the p-norms?

Comment: The index in Rudin's book has an entry for polar coordinates. Polar coordinates are useful to decide integrability of functions which depend only on the norm.